# I have a rails app with devise but con confimations through email sends me to a russian webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mandrill

I have my rails app configured with Mandrill API and devise

for example: I want to confirm my user through the email that my app sends me. When I click the link, it sends me to a russian webpage http://sistema.com/domashnjaja-stranica/

What is going on???

Comment: what's the link you get in your email ?

Comment: mandrillapp.com/track/click/30229622/sistema.com?p=aoijfosidjfeiru....a bunch of letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two possibilities in my mind: it's possible that the API keys you are using someone else is using too, or that perhaps settings in your production.rb or application.rb are wrong.

When you set up mandrill, you probably checkmarked the option for analytics for open rates and click tracking, which makes all URL's in your emails get wrapped with a mandrill url (mandrillapp.com/etc...). You can see in the url you posted that it's doing just that. I'd first check all my mandrill settings in the dashboard to see what other options have been set, such as default host, etc. With that in mind, here's a few other things to check:

**production.rb / application.rb checks**

In your environments folder, check production.rb and application.rb for the following line:

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] }`

Specifically, you should see if there is a different host set there (if you are loading the variable in like I am through an environmental variable, be sure to check your .env file as well).

**Mandrill API keys being used by another developer**

1. It's possible that another developer *stole* your API credentials to use for their application. This could be because both your private and public key was available in your code was publicly viewable, either through your site, or, if you pushed both your public and private mandrill key to a open repository on Github or Bitbucket (as in, they weren't added to a .gitignore).
2. If Mandrill's validation process when creating API key's is not great, it could have generated an API key that had been decommissioned, or  already in use by another customer. I'd highly doubt this, however, as you'd assume not only the keys they generate would have a low collision rate, but they'd also make sure they were unique on creation, and not used, even if the account had been deleted.
3. If you mistyped your API keys in the application, there could be a very rare chance that you entered another valid API key from another user.

The easiest way to fix this would be to decommission the old API keys, and generate new ones. I'd also change the password on the mandrill account, in case it's been compromised. I'd then check through my mandril settings to make sure there isn't a url set anywhere for that URL.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was that in file production.rb I set up a different host!